# Replacing a line of text in an android external text file

Tags: android, io, text-files

I just want to delete 2 lines of text from a text file that I created. Currently, this is what I'm trying to get rid of the 2 lines:

```
private void deleteDataFromFile(String title, String Date) {

        try {
            //open the file
            FileInputStream myIn= openFileInput(FILENAME);
            //the reader given the input file stream.
            InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(myIn);
            //Aftert he inputstream is open, need also a bufferedReader
            BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(inputReader);

            //holds a line of input
            String line;

            //used for only erasing one date.
            int counter = 0;

            while ((line = BR.readLine()) != null && counter < 1) {
                if (line.equals(title)) {
                    line.replace(title, "" + "\n");
                    line = BR.readLine();
                    line.replace(Date, "" + "\n");
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            BR.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

I realize that since I'm using the replace function on a string it has no effect on the actual file itself, but I can not find any other function in the IO library to affect the text file. What I'm thinking about doing is creating a new file on the phone with the exact contents of this file and just deleting the 2 lines from it. That seems troublesome and inefficient though, and I'd like to avoid it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Best way would probably be to just rewrite the entire file, as you parse through the file append everything to a secondary buffer that includes your changes then overwrite the original file.  Also you should stick to the java convention that variable names always start with lower case.

Comment: Thanks. I only had one variable BR?

Comment: Also, your parameter Date, if you had imported one of the classes called Date this would cause a conflict.